# Parsing an array of json objects in GO

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, go, slice

I am trying to parse given API response into a struct.
It seems to be an array.

```
[
   {
      "host_name" : "hostname",
      "perf_data" : "",
      "plugin_output" : "All good",
      "state" : 0
   }
]
```

I cannot figure out how to create **struct** for it, I came up with:

```
type ServiceData struct {
    HostName     string `json:"host_name"`
    PerfData     string `json:"perf_data"`
    PluginOutput string `json:"plugin_output"`
    State        int    `json:"state"`
}
```

```
defer resp.Body.Close()
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
buf.ReadFrom(resp.Body)
jsonStr := buf.String()
var servicedata ServiceData
json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &servicedata)
```

But no luck.

Should I perhaps remove square brackets from the initial response?
Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just want to note that the JSON response is an array of objects containing a single object. You were trying to parse it into a single object and was failing. Creating a variable that is and array of `ServiceData` fixes the issue as per the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may unmarshal JSON arrays into Go slices. So unmarshal into a value of type `[]ServiceData` or `[]*ServiceData`:

```
var servicedata []*ServiceData
```

A working demo:

```
func main() {
    var result []*ServiceData
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &result); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v", result[0])
}

const src = `[
   {
      "host_name" : "hostname",
      "perf_data" : "",
      "plugin_output" : "All good",
      "state" : 0
   }
]`
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XxmQ-Rd7KQF)):

```
&{HostName:hostname PerfData: PluginOutput:All good State:0}
```

Also note that you may unmarshal "directly from the body", no need to read the body first.

Use [`json.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) to do that:

```
var servicedata []*ServiceData
if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&result); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
```

It's much shorter, easier to read and it's more efficient.

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing. Thanks